# Use ant to wrap html code in static template

Tags: ant, build-automation

I have several HTML files located in different places (in a common root), like this:

```
index.html
moduleA/list.html
moduleA/add.html
moduleB/list.html
moduleB/add.html
...
```

Additionally I have one file called _template.html, that contains HTML code and a placeholder `#CONTENT#`.
What I need:

1. Copy all HTML files to public/ directory
2. Each HTML file in public/ directory should also have code from _template.html wrapped around the original content.

I use ANT to copy the files, but I cannot figure out how to wrap the template-code around the code...
My ANT script looks like this:

```
<project default="build">
    <target name="build">
        <copy todir="${dir.intermediate}/temp">
            <fileset dir="${dir.source}" includes="**/*.html"/>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

---

**Example:**

index.html

```
<div>This is the index-page</div>
```

_template.html

```
<html>
    <head><title>Page-Title</title></head>
    <body>
        #CONTENT#
    </body>
</html>
```

Should generate output file:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Page-Title</title></head>
    <body>
        <div>This is the index-page</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible workaround if you want to stick with built-in ant tasks would be to separate your template file into two files, a "pre" section like this:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Page-Title</title></head>
  <body>
```

and a "post" section like this:

```
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you could use the [`concatfilter`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#concatfilter) in a `filterchain` inside your `copy` task:

```
<copy todir="${dir.intermediate}/temp">
  <fileset dir="${dir.source}" includes="**/*.html"/>
  <filterchain>
    <concatfilter prepend="src/_template_pre.html" append="src/_template_post.html" />
  </filterchain>
</copy>
```

I can't see any way of doing this with a single template file without using something like ant-contrib or scripting.

Comment: Thanks! This solution is simple and effective. I was able to solve my problem within 3 minutes after reading this answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's perfectly possible with pure ant tasks :

First use loadfile to load the "replacement" string into a property :

```
<loadfile property="replacement" srcFile="index.html"/>
```

Then after copying your template somehwere, where the final file will be do this :

```
<replaceregexp file="${my.final.file}"
               match="#CONTENT#"
               replace="${replacement}"
/>
```

That's it your file should now be the desired one :)

Comment: That would only work for a single file though. You'd have to do more to wrap all the files in a fileset.

Comment: @matt This can be part of a target, and the target can be called multiple times with ant-contrib foreach task. If you want an example about that let me know :)

Comment: This solution has style, I like it! However, it takes additional scripting to apply it to many files (for-loop + extra target) which would make my already huge ant script even bigger and more difficult to maintain.